# K Fold cross validation with matrices

Tags: python, validation, matrix

Here is my original code without cross-validation.

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model = model.fit(matrix_tmp, label_tmp)
print("Entered 1")
y_train_pred = model.predict(matrix_tmp_test)
```

Here matrix_tmp, label_tmp and matrix_tmp_test are matrices.
 I wish to use K fold cross validation here.

```
model = SGDClassifier()
cv=cross_validation.KFold(len(matrix_tmp), n_folds=5)
results=[]

for traincv, testcv in cv:
   model = model.fit(matrix_tmp[traincv],   label_tmp[traincv]).predict(matrix_tmp_test[testcv])
   results.append( Error_function)
print "Results:" + str(np.array(results).mean())
```

This doesn't seem to be working. Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that without concrete example, I am not able to offer valuable suggestion. However, I think you could try to use cross_validation.train_test_split which could make more sense and less chance to have errors.

Comment: Hi, but I wish to use Kfold CV for determining estimator performance. I have already used train_test_split earlier before generating the matrices.